# codeigniter forbidden access when accessing upload_form

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am a student n just started using codeigniter to develop a website using codeigniter 3.1.6 and xampp

I got forbidden access error when accessing upload_form.php

[image: forbidden access error 403]
here's my apache config

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.


    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

here's my code
main.php in application/views

```
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-red w3-collapse w3-top w3-large w3-padding" style="z-index:3;width:300px;font-weight:bold;" id="mySidebar"><br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-button w3-hide-large w3-display-topleft" style="width:100%;font-size:22px">Close Menu</a>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <a href="application/views/upload_form.php"><h3 class="w3-padding-64"><b>Arnold<br>Cells</b></h3></a>
  </div>
```

upload_form.php in application/views

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php in application/controllers

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
}
?>
```

can someone help me to fix this, please ? 
Thank you

Comment: If you haven't rewrite your .htaccess to bypass index.php then you have to enter your access page URL accordingly

Comment: You are not supposed to input view file in URL directly. Rather route which is usually represented like `base_url('upload/index')` (`base_url()` helper function will work since you have loaded url helper in constructor). Follow [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide) which is fairly well written. You are [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#try-it), but for some reason you stopped following documentation example and tried to use your own like-to-be URL `http://localhost/cells/application/views/upload_form.php`. Just follow basic docs' examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the Hayk's answer or Tpojka's comment are not clear you should change this line in main.php

```
<a href="application/views/upload_form.php"><h3 class="w3-padding-64"><b>Arnold<br>Cells</b></h3></a>
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url("upload/index");?>"><h3 class="w3-padding-64"><b>Arnold<br>Cells</b></h3></a>
```

This will make the link open the upload form.

The error is because the "application/views/" folder cannot be access directly by way of a browser request.

Comment: well, i tried using "<?php echo base_url("upload/index");?>" as you said it works but now an "Object not found" came out, at least it's not forbidden access anymore lol...already tried "<?php echo base_url("upload");?>" and "<?php echo base_url("upload.php");?>" still object not found..

Comment: What's the name of the object not found?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you shouldn't load your views with direct link to it,
they should be loaded from specific controller/action.
As i see you have already action which are loading your upload_form view
 
so you can replace href of your a tag to action which are loading the view, inthis example will be like

```
<?=base_url()."upload/index";?>
```

and be sure 'url' helper loaded by autoloading